# Zoom keeps following current workspace

Tags: linux, workspace, zoom-meeting

I am using bspwm on debian. Because of pandemic, we have to use Zoom for online classes. Something annoying that happens is that when i switch workplaces on bspwm, sometimes the Zoom screen "follows" to the workspace i switch into, which is quite annoying. Is there a simple way to prevent this from happening?